# Is Late 2016 MacBook Pro 13" Capable of 3440 x 1440 @ 100 Hz?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

I have a Late 2016 MacBook Pro 13" laptop and I am considering buying the [Samsung CF791](http://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/curved/34--cf791-wqhd-monitor-lc34f791wqnxza/) 34" monitor, capable of 3440 x 1440 @ 100 Hz resolution. I realize I may need to buy an adapter, such as the [USB-C to DisplayPort Adapter Cable](https://www.startech.com/AV/usb-c-video-adapters/usb-c-displayport~CDP2DPMM1MB) from StarTech, but I'm concerned I won't be able to get 100 Hz from this cable and/or the built-in video card won't support that resolution and refresh rate.

If I buy this monitor and cable, will I be able to use the Mac at 3440 x 1440 @ 100 Hz resolution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Startech adapter didn't work for me with the Samsung CF791 (the monitor was not getting any signal and I had to return the cable). I did however get 3440x1440 @ 100 Hz using the [Anker USB-C to HDMI adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MYUCWOK). You can see it here: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While I ended up returning the CF791 (5 out of 5 CF791 monitors had several dead pixels and text clarity was awful compared to Dell U3415W, which I ended up going with instead), it's good to know Macbook Pro is capable of 100 Hertz refresh rate with the Anker USB-C to HDMI adapter.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/

> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display at millions of colors and:
>
> - One display with 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
> - Up to two displays with 4096-by-2304 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors

Comment: ...In other words, yes to that resolution but likely not at 100Hz

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping one could get more refreshes (Hz) in at a lower resolution, i.e. 3440 x 1440 @ 100 Hz vs. 5120 x 2880 @ 60 Hz.